# Regex not working in jquery for form validation

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am runing the following jquery script:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#textThing").blur(function(){
    var isNumber = $("#textThing").val().match(/^\d+/);

    $("#p2").html(isNumber);
  });
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="textThing" />
<p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the p2 never gives me anything when I deselect the input. What did I do wrong?

Comment: #Folio is the selector for ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say:

```
$("#p2").html(isNumber == null ? "" : isNumber[0]);
```

instead of:

```
$("#p2").html(isNumber);
```

...because `.match()` returns an array if matched. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/k45Ka/5/

Comment: try entering non numeric, always returns array if there is a match, null if not, so your fiddle throws error

Comment: Great option, just that if you don't type anything, it doesn't display the new result. Why?

Comment: @rickyman20, what do you want it to display if nothing is typed? As is, the logic is that it will not match, so it will not update p2.

Comment: So, it returns null or undefined?

Comment: Oh, ok. Now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/r4VPZ/3/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/r4VPZ/4/

You can see `.match` explaination above.

You can also use `.toString` with `.html` or `.text` api. You can do a `null` handling or look into `isNaN` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Hope it helps, please let me know if I missed anything, cheers `:)`

Good read: http://api.jquery.com/html/ **&** http://api.jquery.com/text/

`Match` : What does `.match` returns : [learning regex and jquery - what does .match return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435007/learning-regex-and-jquery-what-does-match-return)

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#textThing").on("blur",function(){
    var isNumber = $("#textThing").val().match(/^\d+/);

     $("#p2").html(isNumber.toString());
    // $("#p2").text(isNumber);
  });
});

//var folioIsNumResult = $("#Folio").val().match(/^\d+/i);​​
```

Answer (score 1):

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/TbCfc/

match returns null when the regex is not matched!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#textThing").blur(function(){
    var isNumber = $(this).val().match(/^\d+/);
      if(isNumber == null){
          var res = "not a number"
              }else{
              var res = "valid number";
              }
    $("#p2").html(res);
  });
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating any text values to put in if test passes or fails

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/9MJNj/

```
   $("#p2").html(isNumber ? 'Is number':'Is not');
```

Comment: returns array if there are matches annd null if not, so is not exactly a boolean, but can be used as if/else. Not 100% sure what you wanted in text, assumed this is validation error for user